# How do I remove a button from a view controller's toolbar on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, toolbaritems

I have code that works great for adding a button to the toolbar:

```
NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,shuffleBarItem,flexibleSpace,nil];
self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
```

However, I also want to be able to remove toolbar items.  When I use the below method, my application crashes:

```
NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,nil];
self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;
```

Does anyone know how I can dynamically alter the toolbar on the iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it into a `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray* _toolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 3]; 
[ _toolbarItems addObjects: flexibleSpace,shuffleBarItem,flexibleSpace,nil];

self.toolbarItems = _toolbarItems;
```

When you want to remove items from the array:

```
NSInteger indexOfItem = ...
[ _toolbarItems removeObjectAtIndex: indexOfItem ];

self.toolbarItems = _toolbarItems;
```

**Note that in this case you should not use `removeObject` since you have repeating objects in your array, and calling `[ _toolbarItems removeObject: flexibleSpace ]` will actually remove both instances of `flexibleSpace` in the array**

Comment: This all will work, but it won't update the display of the toolbar.  You need to call setToolbarItems: (one way or another) to trigger the update.

Comment: Also the code above that crashes, doesn't.  Something else is causing the crash.

Comment: @paull Assigning properties **implicitly** calls `setToolbarItems` :)

Comment: toolbarItems is an NSArray* so your method does not work.  i guess you can assign an NSMutableArray to toolbarItems but when you reference toolbarItems in the future to remove objects, it will not respond to the mutable selectors

Comment: @paul - try setting the toolbarItems twice. i am pretty sure that is causing the crash

Comment: @jacob yes, that's why I said "one way or another".

@Tony - setting an NSMutableArray to toolbarItems does allow mutable calls to toolbarItems to work - I was a little surprised, but not too much.

Comment: @paull - you are right.  i was getting the "not responds to selector" warning but it disappeared when i made toolbarItems a class member. for some reason i still get a crash when removing the items from the mutable array.  could it have something to do with toolbarItems getting auto-released when I say self.toolbarItems = toolbarItems?

Comment: Be careful - toolbarItems is a property of UIViewController, and making a instance variable or even a local variable with the same name will either fail, or turn around and bite you.  Make sure that you have no compiler warnings in your code.

Answer (score 1):

To remove items from the front or back, you could use `subarrayWithRange`, i.e.:

```
NSRange allExceptLast;
allExceptLast.location = 0;
allExceptLast.length = [self.toolbarItems count] - 1;
self.toolbarItems = [self.toolbarItems subarrayWithRange:allExceptLast];
```

If you want to remove objects from the middle, you could either use `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` (which might be overly complicated), or brute force:

```
NSMutableArray *mutToolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.toolbarItems];
[mutToolbarItems removeObjectAtIndex:<index of object>];
self.toolbarItems = mutToolbarItems;
```

Note that you shouldn't send `removeObjectAtIndex:` to `self.toolbarItems` directly (even if you use the above method), since `toolbarItems` is exposed as an `NSArray`--you'll get a compiler warning, and possibly a crash (since you have no control over whether it will actually be implemented as an `NSMutableArray` behind the scenes).

Comment: i agree that it's probably better to treat it as NSArray, even though Jacob was right that I could send removeObjectAtIndex.  anyway, this line crashes my app - NSMutableArray *mutToolbarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.toolbarItems];

Comment: Are you doing this before you've set `self.toolbarItems`?  If so, that would cause it to crash.  Otherwise, my guess would be that you're over-releasing `self.toolbarItems` somewhere.  Are you ever sending it `release`?  (You shouldn't, since whenever you set it, it will automatically release the old value.)